# The expected area of a triangle made up three points picked randomly inside a circle of radius, and contains the center

Tags: probability, geometry

Consider the triangle formed by randomly distributing three points Inside a circle. What is the expected area of the triangle that contains the center of the circle. 
And what is the expected area of the intersection of a set of dependent trinagles that contain the center?

Thank you in  advance for your help.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: Randomly ditributed how? Is the probability that a given point lies within a given shape proportional to the area of said shape?

Comment: I mean the points are uniformly distributed inside a circle.

Comment: Interesting problem. The probability for the triangle contains the center is $\frac14$ and the expected area of the triangle conditional to it contains the center is $\frac{4}{3\pi}$. Though I wonder whether this is a homework problem.

Comment: This is not a homework problem, it make part of more complex problem that I try to resolve. Could you please give me more explanation about how you drive the probability $1/4$, I think that this probability is for the case where the three points of the triangle are on the circle, but in my problem the three points area INSIDE the circle.

Comment: Any suggestion about the intersection problem?

Comment: If one can compute, $\varphi(r)$, the probability density for a point at a distance $r$ from the center falls within a triangle ( condition to the triangle contains the origin ), then the expected area of intersection of $N$ independently and uniformly chosen triangles will be proportional to an integral of $\varphi(r)^N dr^2$. However, even figure out the correct form of $\varphi(r)$ is a nightmare...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This base part of the problem is not that hard because for suitable chosen coordinates, the condition that the center falls inside the triangle is relatively simple.

WOLOG, assume the circle is the unit circle.

Let $(r_i, \alpha_i), i = 1,2,3$ be the positions of the 3 random points in polar coordinates.
Because of the symmetry of the problem. It just suffices to look the case where $\alpha_1 = 0$ and $0 \le \alpha_2 \le \pi$.

Let $\theta = \alpha_2$ and $\phi = 2\pi - \alpha_3$. It is easy to check for the triangle to contain the origin, the condition is given by $0 \le \phi \le \pi$ and $\theta + \phi \ge \pi$. (*see image at end for an illustration*)

From this, we see the probability for the triangle to contain the origin is given by:

$$\int_0^\pi \frac{d\theta}{\pi}\int_{\pi-\theta}^\pi \frac{d\phi}{2\pi} \iiint_{0\le r_i\le1}  dr_1^2 dr_2^2 dr_3^2 = \frac{1}{2\pi^2}\int_0^\pi\theta d\theta = \frac14$$

When the triangle contains the origin, its area is given by:

$$\frac12 r_1 r_2 \sin\theta + \frac12 r_1 r_3 \sin\phi + \frac12 r_2 r_3 \sin(2\pi-(\theta+\phi))\tag{*}$$

Using symmetry of the problem again and notice $\int_0^1 r_i dr_i^2 = \frac23$, 
the contribution to expected area *when the triangle contains the origin* is given by:
$$\int_0^\pi \frac{d\theta}{\pi}\int_{\pi-\theta}^\pi \frac{d\phi}{2\pi} \left[\frac32 \left(\frac23\right)^2 \sin\theta \right] = \frac{1}{3\pi^2}\int_0^\pi \theta\sin\theta d\theta = \frac{1}{3\pi}\tag{**}$$

As a result, the conditional expected area of the triangle when it contains the origin is $\frac{4}{3\pi}$.

[image: A circle showing allowed region]

---

**UPDATE**

There are higher dimension generalization on the probability of picking a triangle containing the origin. Quoting from an
[article](http://lsusmath.rickmabry.org/psisson/putnam/putnam-web.htm) 
by R.Howard and Paul Sisson, we have:

> Let $\mathbb{R}^n$ be endowed with a probability measure $\mu$ which is symmetric with
>   respect to the origin and such that when $n+1$ points are chosen
>   independently with respect to $\mu$, with probability one their convex
>   hull is a simplex. Then the probability that the origin is contained
>   in the simplex generated by $n+1$ such random points is $\frac{1}{2^n}$.

---

**UPDATE2** What does *the contribution to expected area* means.

In general, when you uniformly pick 3 points from a circle, it need not enclose the
center. Let $T$ be a variable running through all possible configuration of the 3 points.
Let $\mathscr{A}(T)$ be the area of corresponding triangle and $d\mu(T)$ be the probability density of occurrence of $T$. Let $\mathscr{C}$ be the set of configuration where the triangle contains the origin.

The expected area of the unconstrained triangle is given by

$$\int \mathscr{A}(T) d\mu(T)$$

The expected area of the triangle conditional to it contains the center is given by:

$$\frac{\int_{\mathscr{C}} \mathscr{A}(T) d\mu(T)}{\int_{\mathscr{C}} d\mu(T)}$$

The numerator here is what I mean "*contribution to expected area*"
and the denominator $\int_{\mathscr{C}} d\mu(T) = \frac14$ is
the probability for the triangle to contain the origin.

For $T \in \mathscr{C}$, one can setup coordinates so that $\mathscr{A}(T)$ has
the simple form in $(*)$. By symmetry, the contribution for those 3 pieces in $(*)$
equal to each other. This explains the factor $\frac32$ appear in the integrand
of L.H.S of $(**)$. The remaining part of the integrand in $(**)$ comes from the partial integral over $r_i$:
$$ \iiint_{0\le r_i \le 1} dr_1^2 dr_2^2 dr_3^2\;r_1 r_2 \sin \theta =
   \left(\frac23\right)\left(\frac23\right)\left(1\right) \sin\theta = \left(\frac23\right)^2 \sin\theta $$

Comment: Then The probability for the triangle to contain the origin in the general case (when the radius = R)  is $(R^3 R^3 R^3)/3 3 3/4 $  ??

Comment: No idea what you are talking about. If you uniformly pick the vertices from a circle of radius $R$. The "radial part" of the  probability density picks up an extra factor $\left(\frac{1}{R^2}\right)^3$ but the probability for the triangle to contain the origin remains the same.

Comment: what about the conditional expected area of the triangle when it contains the origin and the radius is R?

Comment: The conditional expected area will be scaled by a factor of $R^2$.

Comment: Are you sure about the expected area? My own [naive simulation](http://ideone.com/Sd0aQO) suggests a value more like $\approx 0.03$, while your $\frac4{3\pi}\approx 0.42$. So either I garbled my area computation, or there is a mistake somewhere in your deduction.

Comment: @MvG, I've double checked my numbers by a $10^7$ simulations before I compose this answer. My simulations give me an estimate 0.249799 for the probability and 0.424439 for the expected area.

Comment: OK, my mistake, should have *added* the terms instead of multiplying them. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Now for the intersection we should start by four points which draw four triangles and only two of them should contain the center

Comment: my simulation much exactely the resualt mad

Comment: my simulation much exactely the resualt made by achille hui.

Comment: It is an interesting problem, could you please **achille hui** give us more detail about the formula for one triangle in the general case, i.e radius=$R$
In the case where N traingles are independent, I think that the intersection area is equal to the expected area of one triangle powerd N.

Comment: An other way to derive the probability  $1/4 $ that a triangle contains the origin is given in http://brainden.com/forum/index.php/topic/9750--/.

Comment: Please achillle hui, what you mean by "the contribution to expected area". Could you please give us more explanation about the different steps to achieve the previous results "$(4/3*Pi) R^2$". Thanks

Comment: If you uniformly pick 3 points from a circle, the triangle it formed need not enclose the center. What we done is integrate the same "area functional" you used for such unconstrained triangles but limit the domain of integration to those triangles which contain the origin. The term "contribution to expected area" really means "contribution to the integral of expected area of unconstrained triangles".

Comment: thank you, but it is not yet not very clear for me.

Comment: I updated the answer to fill in more details.

Comment: Thank you very much it is now clear, one more question is why you use $d r^2$ and not $d r$

Comment: The probability density is $2rdr = d(r^2)$. I move the normalization constant $2$ inside $d(\cdots)$ so that when a degree of freedom is irrelevant, you can simply remove it from the integral.

Comment: yes, I mean why $2r dr$ and not $r dr$

Comment: $\int_0^1 rdr = \frac12$. The general idea is to group the probability density of each degree of freedom together as single unit. If you don't need a degree of freedom, you can get rid of that term at one place. That's why the integral over $\theta$ is written as $\int_0^\pi \frac{d\theta}{\pi}$ and the integral over $\phi$ is written as $\int_{\pi-\theta}^{\pi} \frac{d\phi}{2\pi}$.