# expected area of the intersection of a set of triangles made up points inside a circle, and the triangles must contain the origin

Tags: probability, geometry

What is the expected area of the intersection of a set of triangles made up N points that are picked uniformly inside a circle. The triangles must contain the origin of the circle?
The expected area of one random triangle that contain a circle of radius R is given by : $ 4/(3 \Pi) R²$, see : [The expected area of a triangle made up three points picked randomly inside a circle of radius, and contains the center](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321332/the-expected-area-of-a-triangle-made-up-three-points-picked-randomly-inside-a-ci)

Comment: i guess, Due to symmetry, expected value would be the area when are points are equidistant on circle.

Comment: If all the $N$ points lie on the same half of the circle, no triangle will contain the origin.

Comment: i meant if every two consecutive points subtend an angle of $2\pi/N$ at the center. The area corresponding to this arrangement might be the expected value.

Comment: and what about the distance from the points to the center, should be the same for all points?

Comment: Please don't intentionally duplicate questions.